# Deleting a Realm object in a SwiftUI List with cascading delete

Tags: list, swiftui, realm, cascading-deletes

I've been reading through the Realm SwiftUI tutorial doc at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui-tutorial/ and studying their sample code.  That code (specifically the version that does not use Atlas device sync) shows an example of deleting a row in a SwiftUI list by calling `onDelete(perform:)`.  This is great for deleting the underlying Realm object that corresponds to the row but if that object has a property that represents a "to-many" relationship (i.e., a List), those objects obviously don't get deleted since Realm doesn't perform "chaining" or "cascading" deletes for you.  Here's a simple example implementation based on the sample code in the Realm tutorial:

```
class WidgetContainer: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var widgets = List<Widget>()
}

class Widget: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
}
```

And here's the view code:

```
struct WidgetContainerView: View {

    @ObservedResults(WidgetContainer.self) var widgetContainers
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(widgetContainers) { container in
                WidgetContainerDetailView(container: container)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: $widgetContainers.remove)
        }
    }
}
```

That `onDelete(perform:)` will obviously delete the backing `WidgetContainer` object but not any `Widget` objects that might be in the container's `.widgets` list property.  I've been reading through the Realm docs to understand how to implement this myself and I think I've managed to get it working but I'm wondering if there is a better/easier way to do this.  Here's the method that I currently have implemented:

```
struct WidgetContainerView: View {

    @ObservedResults(WidgetContainer.self) var widgetContainers
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(widgetContainers) { container in
                WidgetContainerDetailView(container: container)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete(at:))
        }
    }
    
    private func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for i in offsets {
            if let widgetContainer = $widgetContainers.wrappedValue[i].thaw() {
                try? widgetContainer.realm?.write {
                    widgetContainer.realm?.delete(widgetContainer.widgets)
                }
            }
            $widgetContainers.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or thoughts on ways to improve this or potential problems I should be aware of?  Thanks very much!

Comment: One of the reasons cascade deletes are challenging as Realm objects can be related to other objects; for example; suppose there's a Owner and Dog class; each Owner can have a related Dog. I am the owner of my dog, Spot. My wife also owns Spot. If you cascade delete me (which then deletes Spot), what happens to my wifes dog? If you want cascade delete abilities, consider Embedded objects they cascade delete when the parent object is deleted. Other than that, your code works for this use case.